# Is there a way to separate kafka topic serdes from materialized serdes?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to decouple the encoding format in a Kafka topic from the encoding format used to cache the data locally in a kafka streams app.
Is there a way of doing this that does not require me to create an extra step (kafka-topic)?

The input topic is a table-formatted-topic, meaning a null value for a key should delete the entry in the resulting table.

I found the following option lacking due to the extra step required:

```
s1 = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(inputKeySerde, inputValueSerde));
s2 = s1.through("intermediate-topic",  Produced.with(intermediateKeySerde, intermediateValueSerde));
t1 = builder.table("intermediate-topic", Consumed.with(intermediateKeySerde, intermediateValueSerde), t1Materialized);
```

An alternative could be using the processor API and simply forwarding the entries to the store, however this would create an extra internal changelog topic.

Is there an alternative that does not require me to create an extra step?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it differently. However, I don't see *why* you would want to change the encoding?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.
The reason for changing encoding format is to be able to order the results when performing interactive queries (mostly for range queries). 
We use protobuf as an encoding format and the variable length makes the encoded keys not correctly byte comparable.
After some digging through Kafka internals, I don't see why we should have to use the same serdes for a topic and a store, but the API seems to enforce this anyway.

Comment: I see. Feel free to open a JIRA. On reason to enforce the same encoding is for source-topic KTables -- it allows to not duplicate the data into an additional changelog topic, but use the input topic for recovery.

Comment: Done: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7777